# Given a function from an array to an array, compute the linear approximation of the function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods

Suppose I have a function that takes an input as a numpy array (vector) and outputs another vector after performing some non-linear transformation. I have provided a simple, illustrative example here :

```
def generalized_function(input_array):
    """
        Input array is a 3D function, output array is a
        non linear function of the input parameters
    """
    x,y,z = input_array
    output_array = [x**2+2*y, y**3-4*x+5*y, -z**2-2*x*y]
    return np.array(output_array)
```

In this case, I can easily compute the linear approximation of this function (the Jacobian) manually. In much larger cases, how would I go about computing this approximation? Is there a numpy/scipy function that does this for me?

Comment: If you're willing to use other packages, you can use automatic differentiation to do this for you - for instance [jax.jacfwd](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.jacfwd.html)

Comment: And if you want to stay with numpy/scipy, you can also use [scipy.optimize.approx_fprime](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.approx_fprime.html)

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to approximate generalized_function() which (in this example) is a f(x, y, z) --> (i, j, k) right?

Comment: @Nin17 thanks! That is exactly what I want it to do!

Comment: @OskarHofmann Thanks! Do you know how its accuracy and speed compares to the JAX suggestion?

Comment: @UmbertoFontanazza yes, that is correct, it is a function from $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: `approx_fprime` will almost certainly be slower (particularly for large Jacobians) and less accurate than the jax jacobian functions, as it uses finite differences [this](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/autodiff_cookbook.html) is the relevant part of the jax docs which discusses this